# AWS-SDK-Go Can't delete object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I want to delete the key(`bucket/userID/fileName`) using AWS-SDK-Go.
But this code doesn't delete the `userID` key.

```
config := model.NewConfig()

sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(config.AWSS3Region)},
)

svc := s3.New(sess)

input := &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(config.AWSS3Bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(userID + "/"),
}

result, err := svc.DeleteObject(input)
```

I can delete `bucket/userID/fileName` but I can't delete `bucket/userID`.

Comment: Are there other objects at `bucket/userID/`? If there is more than one object with that key prefix this won't work.

Comment: @Briansbum thanks comment. Yes. There are many files under the `bucket/userID`. Which means, I have to delete the all file which is under the `bucket/userID/*` and delete `bucket/userID`?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response, you do yes.

Comment: @Briansbum Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code to delete Objects from S3.

```golang
import(
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func configS3() *s3.Client {

    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(os.Getenv("S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID"), os.Getenv("S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"), "")
    
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithCredentialsProvider(creds), config.WithRegion(os.Getenv("S3_REGION")))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } 

    return s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)

}

func DeleteImageFromS3(echoCtx echo.Context) error {
    
    awsClient := configS3()

    input := &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:    aws.String("pic.jpg"),
    }

    _, err := awsClient.DeleteObject(context.TODO(), input)

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("Got an error deleting item:")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return 

    }

    return echoCtx.JSON(http.StatusOK, "Object Deleted Successfully")

}
```

For further reference, please check this https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/code-examples/s3/deleteobject/